# jQuery TOOLS datepicker - open the calendar after click on the button

Tags: jquery

Probably it's really easy to do, but I don't have more ideas for now :( So please help me if you know how.

I use the jQuery TOOLS datepicker and my code looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="date" />
<img src="calendar.gif" class="open_calendar" />

$(function() {
   $('.date').dateinput();

   $('.open_calendar').click(function() {
       $('#date').data('dateinput').setValue(0).show();
   });
})
```

i want just open the calendar for the #date input after click on the ".open_calendar" button. How can I do that? The code abote doesn't work unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7uDMC/

Have a look at that and see if it makes sense :)

Comment: Sorry about that try this it makes much more sense

Answer (score 0):

This is built into the jquery tools datepicker.

If you use the trigger option of the datepicker it will create a clickable button for you with a class of `caltrigger`.  You can style the trigger in your css and set a background image for it as well.

Here is what the javascript would look like
`$('.date').dateinput({trigger:true})`

And the css

```
.caltrigger {
 background:url(calendar.gif);
 display:block;
 width:20px;
 height:20px;
}
```

Make sure you alter the width and height to match your image.